# Cordova camera plugin multiple sourcetypes

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to select for example Photo Library and Camera source option to give the user the possibility to take a new photo or use a photo from his phone library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin supports only one at a time. If you want to do this, you'll need to give the user a choice within your app, and then call the plugin with the choice the user made.